# Multiple Search Key in a Matrix

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

I'm trying to solve this problem since some days now but it seems I have reached a dead end. Maybe someone would be able to help me.

I have two sheets. The first one contains the list of my clients and their delivery number depending of the weekday.

[image: Caption 1]

In my second sheet I would like to get the delivery number of the client (red cells) depending of the weekday I select (yellow cells).

[image: Caption 2]

I tried VLOOKUP formula, INDEX/MATCH, QUERY but I wasn't able to find a way to get the delivery number depending of the client's name and the weekday. I think the main issue is that in the first sheet the weekday is a column title.

Maybe the solution is simply to build my tables differently...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is simple vlookup:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A9:A11&B9:B11, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A4&B1:D1&"​​"&B2:D4), "​​"), 2, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful ! I never thought about using VLOOKUP that way. May I ask how/why the formula is auto-filling C9:C11 whenever I change the day in B9:B11 ? Usualy I have to use an ARRAYFORMULA or copy the formula in each cell

Comment: @Spkf INDEX is a type of ARRAYFORMULA with the same functionality just shorter to type in

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, assuming A2 and B2 the cells of first name and first day to look:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1000,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),MATCH(B2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0))
```

Or, if you want this same formula for the full column:

```
=byrow(A2:A,lambda(each,if(each="","",INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1000,MATCH(each,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),MATCH(offset(each,0,1),Sheet1!$1:$1,0)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution works great too. Plus I never knew you could apply INDEX/MATCH formula to the whole column that way. Usualy I copy the formula in each cell since ARRAYFORMULA doesn't work with INDEX/MATCH.

Answer (score 1):

Also doable (are perhaps more simply) using a MAP/FILTER; with your 'Caption 1' table in Sheet1!A1:D4 and your 'Caption 2' table at the top-left of Sheet2, the following in Sheet2!C2 gives you the delivery number for a many names/days as you enter in the columns alongside:

```
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(name,day,ifna(filter(filter(Sheet1!B2:D4,Sheet1!A2:A4=name),Sheet1!B1:D1=day))))
```

N.B. The IFNA blanks out errors for those rows where a Name/Day pair hasn't been entered yet. Extend the ranges in the filter to suit your real data.